# Java socket connection

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I've tried to test socket connection in Java, but failed. Here is my code (two simple applications, server and client):

```
public class TestServer {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1111);
    System.out.println("Server socket created");
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Socket accepted");
    PrintWriter output =  new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
    System.out.println("Output created");
    output.write("Output string");
    socket.close();
    serverSocket.close();       
}
}

public class TestClient {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1111);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("Input: " + input.readLine());
    socket.close();

}

}
```

Output is (after running a server and, after it, client):

```
Server socket created
Socket accepted
Output created
Input: null
```

I've no idea what's the problem and why client didn't receive string sent to it. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually when I use classes like PrintWriter or OutputStream I need to flush its contents to send the data through a socket or write it to a file.

Comment: That's exactly what my problem was. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`input.readLine` expects a newline in the input string. Try to replace the `output.write` with `output.println`.

I just tested it now and it should work correctly like this.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: yeah, sorry, I was in a rush. Should work now.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the other comments, you shouldn't close the socket itself, you should close the outermost output stream you have created around the socket's output stream. That will:

(a) flush the output stream
(b) close it
(c) close the input stream, and
(d) close the socket.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Put the line 

output.flush();

//in the end of the TestServer.java

//and in the TestClient.java I have used the code as given below

Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1111);
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String str;
    while((str=input.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println("Input: " + str);
    }
    socket.close();

}
```